# Ubuntu 18.04 loads to wrong TTY

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 18.04, it was working fine and then an application stopped working. So I reinstalled it and upon booting the background with no mouse or icons appeared. Shortcuts worked. I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 again and the problem persisted. Luckily, I figured out that I can just Ctrl+Alt+F2 into the desktop environment and everything works from there.

I'm just curious about what's going on.